# making an intersecting curve manifold

Tags: bezier-curves

[image]i am using blender to make files for digital fabrication , 3D printing and CNC milling . i am working a little project where i have been sketching with beveled curve , my problem is that when the curve intersects the mesh also interects and i need it as a solid object with no interal vertex . does anyone know a good solution to this problem . i have been just trying to stitch it back together myself but it is time consuming and not great results .

many thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can try to keep only a quarter of it so that you can clean it "by inside" and then apply a mirror in order to obtain the whole shape again.

[image]

The blend here : http://www.pasteall.org/blend/42115

Comment: this does speed things up a little but is there no way to stop the internal vertex to form in the first place . i want to use this technique more than once so it would be nice to find cleaner solution .

Comment: once the curve is converted to mesh, one thing can be tried : assign the inside vertices to a group and shrinkwrap this group to a plane... ?

Comment: Another solution : https://i.gyazo.com/386a2fd12089df20345e628d12e431a5.png. Spin a circle 180° duplicate and bridge them.

Comment: thanks for all the ideas . as i want to use this technique often i needed to find a quick solution to make manifold and loose the internal vertex . the best result i found was to actually export to mesh mixer and make solid then bring back into blender .